# Using Intersect tool Java

Tags: arcobjects, java, intersection

i am trying to pass polyline and polygon feature classes
i am not sure how to pass  the list of features to the Intersect object:

### i tried this method:

```
ArrayList<Object> featuresList = new ArrayList<>();

        FeatureClass polygonfeatureClass = openFeatureClassFromShapeFile(srcShapefilePath, "polygon.shp");
        FeatureClass polylinefeatureClass = openFeatureClassFromShapeFile(srcShapefilePath, "lines.shp");


        Intersect newintersect = new Intersect();
        featuresList.add(polylinefeatureClass);
        featuresList.add(polygonfeatureClass);

        gp = new GeoProcessor();
        gp.setOverwriteOutput(true);
        gp.setTemporaryMapLayers(false);
        gp.setAddOutputsToMap(false);
        gp.setEnvironmentValue("workspace", srcShapefilePath);
```

newintersect.setInFeatures(featuresList)

---

### i get this error :

Item not found in this collection. in 'DAO.Fields'

### com.esri.arcgis.geoprocessing.GeoProcessor.execute(Unknown Source)

i tried to pass the shape files pathes as string too>
i got the same error
then i tried this method:
after i created 2 feature classes in gdb

```
String in1=srcShapefilePath + File.separator + "layers.gdb" + File.separator +            "lines";

       String in2=srcShapefilePath + File.separator +  "layers.gdb" + File.separator + "polygon";
       newintersect.setInFeatures(in1 + ";" + in2);
       gp.execute(newintersect, null);
```

and i got the same error

AutomationException: 0x80004005 - Unspecified error
    at com.esri.arcgis.geoprocessing.GeoProcessor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.esri.arcgis.geoprocessing.GeoProcessor.execute(Unknown Source)

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mashhour-darweish ,Try the below approach.The code is in C# style.
It may be similar in Java too.

```
  Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();     
  GP.OverwriteOutput = true;

  Intersect IntersectDataset = new Intersect();
  IntersectDataset.in_features = "(" + srcShapefilePath+"\\polygon.shp", "polygon.shp" + "; " + srcShapefilePath+"\\lines.shp" + ")";
  IntersectDataset.out_feature_class = srcShapefilePath+"\\myoutput.shp";
  IntersectDataset.output_type = "LINE";

  IGeoProcessorResult result;
  result = (IGeoProcessorResult)GP.Execute(process, null);
```

Comment: i used the same way in your code @Durga an there is no error: String in = "(" + srcShapefilePath + "\\polygon.shp; " + srcShapefilePath + "\\lines.shp)";   that what java accepts.    but what the output.shp  ,  is it an empty shape file which i have created already?

Comment: Intersection of lines.shp and polygon.shp is stored in output.shp.